# Translating field data in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a table named **Item** which has a field named **description**. I am using the Yii framework, and I want to translate the data of the field description according to the language set by the admin. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to leverage the Yii framework for this, you will want to look at:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

In particular, it sounds like you will want to use [CDbMessageSource](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMessageSource)

You will either want to store your `sourcemessage.messsage` key in your description column, and use Yii::t() to translate it, or generate the key dynamically based on your model's class name, primary key, and column name and then use Yii:t().

Comment: I don't see how that will work for dynamic data - happy says that he is trying to translate the contents of item->decription.  CDbMessageSource and Yii::t are designed for static data that you can pre-translate.  i think my original answer is more correct...

Comment: @ChrisB It looks like I interpreted his question differently than you. If he is actually trying to translate the contents of the description field on the fly, then you are correct. Otherwise, if he intends to curate his own translations via some admin functionality, my suggestion would work.

Answer (score 0):

Yii does not have support for this in the core as there's no one true way to organize translation data for tables in your database. There are however some behaviors that may help you, if you accept their DB schema. You could use [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multilingual-behavior). You can also have a look at my [own extension](https://github.com/mikehaertl/translatable). (It works, but is not released yet due to incomplete docs.)

Answer (score -1):

Translations of static data, such as field names, is a core part of Yii.  But translation of data from a database will need to use some third party translation service, like Google translate.